# Массив в качестве параметра

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Во время выполнения задания возник вопрос с передачей статического массива в функцию.
Когда мы используем массив в качестве параметра функции, то, при передаче массива создаётся копия массива и мы работаем с копией, или же передается указатель, и изменения в функции "вытекают" за её пределы, и массив меняется глобально.
А так же, есть ли разница между
void func(int *arr)
void func(int arr[3])

А если более кратко, как передать массив в качестве параметра, чтобы он не изменился глобально
Спасибо!

Comment: Что бы передать по значению, используйте std::array или std::vector.

Comment: Не имею права по условию задачи, увы. Потому и спрашиваю именно за статические массивы.

Comment: Тогда сделать структуру с массивом внутри, и передавать в функцию ее.

Comment: А что вы хотите с ним делать в функции? Обязательно менять? ну, сделайте копию внутри функции... Ответы — "передается указатель, разницы нет". О! передавайте как `const int *` :)